# Frame of data of sparkline is unbalanced

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sparklines

Im using Sparkline with AngularJS, it shows the graphics correctly, the problem is that the frame that shows the data is unbalanced! and I dont know why, this is the problem:

[image]

As you can see the number 7 is out of the frame, I dont know the why of this, and I cant find the style of this frame, anyone knows how to? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fount the solution for this problem, I created the sparkline like this:

```
$('.graphicLine').sparkline(vm.charData,{
        type: 'line',
        height: 80,
        width: '100%',
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: '#dddddd',
        spotColor: '#bbbbbb',
        fillColor: '',
        spotRadius: 3,
        highlightLineColor: '#fff',
        tooltipFormat: '<p>Clientes : {{y}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>'
      });
```

So in the frame the sparkline shows the tooltipFormat, just put in all what you waht to show on the frame